# Работа с объектом

Tags: c#, .net

В Action Script 3 объявляется объектом такой "массив", а как объявить в C#?

```
public static const numbers:Object = {
    1:[1,3],
    2:[5,6]
}
```

И еще вопрос
Получаю из базы данных строку values. Она представляет собой

> {1:1}, {2:0}, {3:1}

Первый параметр Id, второй - значение.
Как эту получаемую строку преобразовать в object (Id, значение) ?

Comment: Не задавайте два вопроса в одном. Создайте две темы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov лимит

Comment: Такой "массив" похож, как мне кажется, на словарь. В C# это будет `Dictionary<int, ?>`. Вместо знака вопроса должен быть второй тип. Я не знаю, что именно представляет из себя `[1,3]` - массив, кортеж, список?

Answer (score 2):

В C# свойства не могут начинаться с цифр, но самым близким по смыслу будет такой код:

```
public static dynamic numbers = new
{
    _1 = new List<int>() { 1, 3 },
    _2 = new List<int>() { 5, 6 }
};
```

А самым нормальным такой

```
List<List<int>> numbers = new List<List<int>>()
{
    new List<int>() { 1, 3 },
    new List<int>() { 5, 6 },
};
```

**UPD**
Можно и словарь, как правильно подсказал @AlexanderPetrov Структуры вполне заменяются друг другом. Можно будет использовать даже `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`, чтобы имитировать свойства.

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> numbers = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>()
{
    { 1 , new List<int>() { 1,3 } },
    { 2 , new List<int>() { 5,6 } }
};
```

---

По второму вопросу надо разбирать строку. Если на коленке, то можно делать так:

```
var values = a.Replace('{', ' ').Replace('}', ' ').Split(',').Select(p => new {
    id = p.Split(':')[0],
    value = p.Split(':')[1],
});
```

Но лучше делать не аналогичные вещи, а переписать это на нормальное ООП на C#. Поскольку ActionScript динамический язык, а C# нет и не особо позволяет определять структуры данных прямо на лету. Точнее такой подход не приветствуется.